Sort By Child Table But Maintain Parent Table Order
I am currently trying to sort the results of two tables in such a way that the primary sort field is one in the child table but would like to keep the parent table results from being moved out of sequence.
An example would be the following tables (using Ms SQL Server) :
CREATE TABLE tier_a(
   idno INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tier_b(
   idno INTEGER NOT NULL,
   tier_a_idno INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tier_a VALUES(3, 'C');
INSERT INTO tier_a VALUES(2, 'B');
INSERT INTO tier_a VALUES(1, 'A');

INSERT INTO tier_b VALUES(1, 1, 'A');
INSERT INTO tier_b VALUES(4, 2, 'C');
INSERT INTO tier_b VALUES(2, 1, 'B');
INSERT INTO tier_b VALUES(5, 3, 'A');
INSERT INTO tier_b VALUES(3, 1, 'C');

If I only sort by the child table :
SELECT tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, tier_b.name AS tier_b_name
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY tier_b_name ASC

I get what I expect :
Ascending by child
tier_a_name | tier_b_name
C           | A
A           | A
A           | B
A           | C
B           | C

Descending by child
tier_a_name | tier_b_name
B           | C
A           | C
A           | B
C           | A
A           | A

But what I am trying to achieve is to still keep the ordering of the parent table :
Ascending by child
tier_a_name | tier_b_name
A           | A
A           | B
A           | C
C           | A
B           | C

Descending by child
tier_a_name | tier_b_name
A           | C
A           | B
A           | A
B           | C
C           | A

I can simulate it with a terrible manual ORDER BY :
Ascending by child
SELECT tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, tier_b.name AS tier_b_name
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY
   CASE
      -- Parent of the Lowest tier_b name (A)
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 1 THEN 1
      -- Parent of the Lowest tier_b name (A) but Higher tier_a idno
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 3 THEN 2
      -- Parent of the Highest tier_b name (C)
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 2 THEN 3
   END,
   tier_b_name ASC

Descending by child
SELECT tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, tier_b.name AS tier_b_name
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY
   CASE
      -- Parent of the Highest tier_b name (C)
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 1 THEN 1
      -- Parent of the Highest tier_b name (C) but Higher tier_a idno
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 2 THEN 2
      -- Parent of the Lowestest tier_b name (A)
      WHEN tier_a.idno = 3 THEN 3
   END,
   tier_b_name DESC


So, you want to ORDER BY (tier A in order of the largest/smallest tier B), (tier B)?
For ascending, that would be:
SELECT 
  tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, 
  tier_b.name AS tier_b_name,
  /*SMALLEST tier_b for each tier_a*/
  tier_a_ordinal = MIN(tier_b.name) OVER (PARTITION BY tier_a.name),
  /*Order of the tier_b value in the tier_a block*/
  tier_b_ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tier_a.name ORDER BY tier_b.name)
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY
  /*First order tier_a by the largest tier_b they have in.*/
  tier_a_ordinal ASC,
  /*If multiple tier_a's have the same largest tier_b, order then _somehow_.*/
  tier_a_name ASC,   
  /*Inside the tier_a's, order them by the tier_b*/
  tier_b_ordinal ASC; 

For descending:
SELECT 
  tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, 
  tier_b.name AS tier_b_name,
  /*LARGEST tier_b for each tier_a*/
  tier_a_ordinal = MAX(tier_b.name) OVER (PARTITION BY tier_a.name),
  tier_b_ordinal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tier_a.name ORDER BY tier_b.name)
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY
  /*First, order by tier_a's by the largest tier_b they have*/
  tier_a_ordinal DESC,  
  /*If multiple have the same largest tier_b, order them _somehow_ */
  tier_a_name DESC,  
  /*Last, order the tier_b's in that tier_a */
  tier_b_ordinal DESC; 

Fiddle

Is that you are looking for?
Ascending by child
SELECT tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, tier_b.name AS tier_b_name
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY tier_a.name, tier_b_name ASC

Descending by child
SELECT tier_a.name AS tier_a_name, tier_b.name AS tier_b_name
FROM tier_a
JOIN tier_b ON tier_b.tier_a_idno = tier_a.idno
ORDER BY tier_a.name, tier_b_name DESC


No, only because this will sort by the parent table first and only then sort by the child table
